# Скачивание файла по прямой ссылке | 403 | PHP

Tags: php, curl, google-drive, file-get-contents, http-status-code-403

Как избежать ошибки 403? Пытался с Google Drive скачать файл по его ID, но после пары удачных попыток пошла ошибка 403 и ничего уже не помогает. Делал так:

```
file_get_contents(https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id={$id})
```

И так тоже:

```
$user_agent = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2';
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Но результатов нет. Как мне обойти эту ошибку?

Примечание: если быть точнее, то, если я делаю сейчас через curl, то получаю ошибку

> We're sorry... ... but your computer or network may be sending
>   automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request
>   right now.

но, как я понял, это одно и тоже.

Comment: Что такое HTTP ошибка 403 смотрели? Понимаете что это такое? Можете посмотреть варианты на англоязычном [SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139698/why-would-curl-and-wget-result-in-a-403-forbidden)

Answer (score 1):

Это так не работает, вам нужно прочитать данную документацию https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php

Comment: Да, с этим я уже разобрался. Пришлось использовать Google Drive API, т.к. мои запросы просто банили. Но теперь возник другой вопрос: сколько обращений возможно таким способом? Например, есть какой-то пост и его посмотрели за сегодня 10к человек (для примера). Так вот, гугл такое позволит? Я слышал, что есть какие-то ограничения, но точно не знаю.